# multi-language feature not working automatically

Tags: magento2, multistore

I have a question. If any body help me on this. that would be good for me.
I have multiple store view (Like: English, French, Spanish etc). I created those store view with currencies in backend and also install language package for each stores. Website default words is translated properly using CSV. But I want to translate the all data Like CMS Page, Products, Categories information without input data in admin in each store view. I have 1M Products and 70 CMS page. It's hard to add other language data for every stores.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to follow admin translation process for this as all data is different for each product , but 1 thing you can do , If you add variable as below for example for product name add below code in your file

```
<?php echo __($product->getName()) ?>
```

and add this product name translation in csv file same thing u can do for all other data

But it is not the right approach as how much data u will add in csv file

See if you are adding translation in csv file better to create product upload csv file with translation and import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all custom text like the product, category details, etc in a particular CSV file. And It's really hard to add all language data for every store.

For multi-language features, you can use Solwin Google Translate Integration Extension for Magento 2 that allows translating the website to more than 90 languages using the Google translation tool.

Refer below link for more details:
https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/google-translate-integration-magento-2/